What is valid fptan argument range for 8087/80287 math coprocessors?
This is historic question.
Intel datasheet says that valid range from 0 to 0.25 *PI.
For Intel 287XL argument absolute value must be lower then 2^63 (as in 80387 and above).
I have system with Am80C287 and this FPU produce valid results for
arguments with absolule value lower then about 0.43 * PI.
For large arguments (not in PI * n + PI / 2 area) FPU return no error and wrong results.
I couldn't find a similar datasheet from AMD.
My question - this is AMD feature or range in Intel understated?

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

By "valid results", do you mean extended precision results accurate to within 5 ulps of the mathematical result, and established across billions of different arguments? Intel's 1987 Programmer's Reference Manual for the 80286/80287 clearly states that effective input to FPTAN  is limited to 0 ≤ Θ ≤ π/4, where Θ = Y/X. AMD's 1989 datasheet for the 80C287 simply states it is "... functionally equivalent to the Intel 80287" and limits itself to electrical specifications. What you are observing is therefore an implementation artifact, not a feature guaranteed by the vendor.

FWIW, I would not expect any functional differences between Intel 80287 and AMD 80C287, because AMD used Intel's 80287 microcode. This led Intel to sue AMD for copyright infringement. The ensuing litigation dragged out for four years (1990-1994);  in the end AMD prevailed.

Your large input

0.45 * PI

gave wrong results because it exceeds the valid input range for Intel's 80287 FPTAN implementation.
Valid input range
intel (1987): 80286 AND 80287 PROGRAMMER'S REFERENCE MANUAL (on PDF page 402) states the valid input range in section 2-12:

FPTAN
0 <= ST(0) <= pi/4

This range limitation can be related to limited microcode size and gave the instruction the subtitle "partial tangent" like following retrocomputing answer elaborates on the restrictions on the range of arguments.
History of 80C287
The AMD 80C287 (80-bit CMOS numeric co-processor, FPU) and its instruction-set (microcode) was apparently a product of re-engineering of the Intel 80287, due to licensing issues at that time; see
AMD 80287 floating-point unit family.
As commented by njuffa, in the datasheet from June 1989 (12 pages scanned copy from Datasheet Archive: 80C287-10 datasheet by Advanced Micro Devices), only some characteristics are claimed:


[..] functionally equivalent to the Intel 80287
compatible with the IEEE floating-point standard 754
adds trigonometric, [..] and arithmetic instructions to the 80C286 instruction set


IEEE floating-point standard 754 from 1985
Since neither instructions nor their specifics are documented there, we can only refer to the mentioned compatibility-standard. It is most likely the older version of 1985, described on Wikipedia: IEEE 754-1985.
This standard and the capacity limitations mentioned there might explain the feature and range specifics observed in the results for the tested arguments.
Compared to newer x87 FPU instruction specifics
Intel 80287XL (387SX micro-architecture)
According to Computing History, the Intel 80287XL Numeric Processing Unit of 1990 is based on the newer i387 core.
The input range is extended as given in the question:

2^63

Also modern AMD models have this extended input range.
AMD64 x87 FPU
For a newer AMD x87 FPU, the official datasheet is published with instructions and their specifics: AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual, Volume 5: 64-Bit Media and x87 Floating-Point Instructions, where the FPTAN operation is specified on page 286:

FPTAN - Floating-Point Partial Tangent
Computes the tangent of the radian value in ST(0), stores the result in ST(0), and pushes a value of 1.0 onto the x87 register stack.
The source value must be between –263 and +263 radians. If the source value lies outside the specified range, the instruction sets the C2 bit of the x87 status word to 1 and does not change the value in ST(0).
Related Instructions:
FCOS, FPATAN, FSIN, FSINCOS
rFLAGS Affected:
None


Mnemonic:  FPTAN
Opcode:  D9 F2
Description: Replace ST(0) with the tangent of ST(0), then push 1.0 onto
the x87 register stack.

See also
Stackexchange questions:

8087 - x87 trigonometric instructions - Retrocomputing Stack Exchange
assembly - FPTAN Example x86 - Stack Overflow

External references:

x87, 80287 - Wikipedia
Fptan - ASM Reference
Embedded Pentium® Processor Family Technical Information Center - Floating-Point Unit
Data Types and Instruction Set of 8087 co-processor


Tnanks.
I print status, ST0 and ST1 after fptan instruction execution and not seen C2 bit set. status=0x3120 or 0x3020 in one case. Now I don't understand why values differs. But in all cases C2 mask is 0x0400 and so C2=0. When arg = 0.45 * PI ST0 contains FFF8-0000-0000-0000 (Nan?), ST1 contain valid number 2.36... Control word=0x037F

@njuffa Used the historic reasoning hint and went back in history, updated my answer and compared the original limitations of the 1980s with the modern input-ranges for x87 trigonometric instructions. If you like to correct or add facts, I oversaw in your comments, feel free.

Calculation of fptan of out of  range arg (1.0E20):
on i5/Linux/Wine status=0x3C20,
on i5/Linux/WMWare/Windows status=0x3C00,
C2=1, but in DOS not.

I test other instruction  - f2xm1 (2^x-1). On 80C287 result valid in arg range from 0.0 to about 0.58. f2xm1(0.585)=0.25 - wrong.
When Borland C++ used interrupt only when arg about 1.5!
On i5 all as described in doc - valid range from -1.0 to 1.0.
